# Python Match Case (Switch) Performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, match

I was expecting the Python `match`/`case` to have equal time access to each case, but seems like I was wrong. Any good explanation why?

Lets use the following example:

```py
def match_case(decimal):
    match decimal:
        case '0':
            return "000"
        case '1':
            return "001"
        case '2':
            return "010"
        case '3':
            return "011"
        case '4':
            return "100"
        case '5':
            return "101"
        case '6':
            return "110"
        case '7':
            return "111"
        case _:
            return "NA"
```

And define a quick tool to measure the time:

```py
import time
def measure_time(funcion):
    def measured_function(*args, **kwargs):
        init = time.time()
        c = funcion(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"Input: {args[1]} Time: {time.time() - init}")
        return c
    return measured_function

@measure_time
def repeat(function, input):
    return [function(input) for i in range(10000000)]
```

If we run each `10000000` times each case, the times are the following:

```py
for i in range(8):
    repeat(match_case, str(i))

# Input: 0 Time: 2.458001136779785
# Input: 1 Time: 2.36093807220459
# Input: 2 Time: 2.6832823753356934
# Input: 3 Time: 2.9995620250701904
# Input: 4 Time: 3.5054492950439453
# Input: 5 Time: 3.815168857574463
# Input: 6 Time: 4.164452791213989
# Input: 7 Time: 4.857251167297363
```

Just wondering why the access times are different. Isn't this optimised with perhaps a lookup table?. Note that I'm not interested in other ways of having equals access times (i.e. with dictionaries).

Comment: @Jab It's Python 3.10.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. This isn't a switch case on primitive data types. It's for *pattern matching*. It is **not a switch*

Comment: There is room for optimization (with all literal patterns, I suspect a lookup table *could* be built), but at this time it does not appear to be optimized.

Comment: Optimization of this using hash/indexing would require that the compiler know in advance the data types of every case value (i.e would only work with constants).  That would be a very narrow special case. I doubt that it would warrant the extra effort given that the objective is pattern matching, not statement dispatch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The match/case statement introduced in [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/) offers a more elegant and readable approach to pattern matching compared to traditional if-elif-else chains. Its primary advantage lies in its ability to streamline complex conditional logic.

### Traditional approach

```
def is_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, Node) and node.children == [LParen(), RParen()]:
        return True
    return (isinstance(node, Node)
            and len(node.children) == 3
            and isinstance(node.children[0], Leaf)
            and isinstance(node.children[1], Node)
            and isinstance(node.children[2], Leaf)
            and node.children[0].value == "("
            and node.children[2].value == ")")
```

### Using match/case

```
def is_tuple(node: Node) -> bool:
    match node:
        case Node(children=[LParen(), RParen()]):
            return True
        case Node(children=[Leaf(value="("), Node(), Leaf(value=")")]):
            return True
        case _:
            return False
```

While it may be equivalent to a dict lookup in the most primitive cases, in general it is not so. Case patterns are designed to look like normal python code but actually they conceal `isinstance` and `len` calls and don't execute what you'd expect to be executed when you see code like `Node()`.

> Essentially this is equivalent to a chain of if ... elif ... else statements. Note that unlike for the previously proposed switch statement, the pre-computed dispatch dictionary semantics does not apply here.

Answer (score 13):

I come late to the party, but I feel like I can add something useful to this thread.
A while back, I published an article on Medium about Python's match-case performance, analyzing the generated byte code and performing benchmarks and comparisons. If you want, you can read the article [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/pythons-match-case-is-too-slow-if-you-don-t-understand-it-8e8d0cf927d). I think it's worth your time.
However, I'm going to summarize it here.

Many programming languages implement their switch-case statements as if they were an if-else sequence. Sometimes the switch-case can be optimized into an efficient lookup table, but that's not always the case.

In Python, this optimization is never performed, thus always resulting in a series of condition checks.

From the article, a speed comparison between if-else and match-case:

```
Average time for match_case:  0.00424 seconds
Average time for if_else:     0.00413 seconds
```

As you can see, they are almost equal.
Plus, if you disassembled the two statements, you would find that they generate nearly identical byte code.

Just a difference to point out, if-else checks call the objects' `__eq__()` method while match-case does the comparisons internally.

Lastly, here's a benchmark that also includes a hash table (dictionary):

```
Average time for match_case:  0.00438 seconds
Average time for if_else:     0.00433 seconds
Average time for dict_lookup: 0.00083 seconds
```

So, if you're keen on performance, you should use hash tables. Although match-case is similar to a C-style switch-case, it's not: match-case is meant to be used for structural pattern matching, and not for replacing performant hash and lookup tables.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to replicate your experiment with another function call `match_if` :

```
def match_if(decimal):
    if decimal == '0':
        return "000"
    elif decimal == '1':
        return "001"
    elif decimal == '2':
        return "010"
    elif decimal == '3':
        return "011"
    elif decimal == '4':
        return "100"
    elif decimal == '5':
        return "101"
    elif decimal == '6':
        return "110"
    elif decimal == '7':
        return "111"
    else:
        return "NA"
```

It appears that if we use the if, elif, else statement is less efficient that the match / case method. Here my results :

```
for i in range(8):
    repeat(match_if, str(i))


Input: 0 Time: 1.6081502437591553
Input: 1 Time: 1.7993037700653076
Input: 2 Time: 2.094271659851074
Input: 3 Time: 2.3727521896362305
Input: 4 Time: 2.6943907737731934
Input: 5 Time: 2.922682285308838
Input: 6 Time: 3.3238701820373535
Input: 7 Time: 3.569467782974243
```

Results match / case :

```
for i in range(8):
    repeat(match_case, str(i))

 Input: 0 Time: 1.4507110118865967
 Input: 1 Time: 1.745032787322998
 Input: 2 Time: 1.988663911819458
 Input: 3 Time: 2.2570419311523438
 Input: 4 Time: 2.54061222076416
 Input: 5 Time: 2.7649216651916504
 Input: 6 Time: 3.1373682022094727
 Input: 7 Time: 3.3378067016601562
```

I don't have a precise answer about why these results, but this experiment show that if we use if statement is little bit longer than the match case.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the two functions generate *very* similar byte code.'

Answer (score 1):

Since python 3.10 it is possible to use **match... case**
with default option (so called wildcard) denoted with `case _`

```py
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#simple-pattern-match-to-a-literal

## Performance

#### if you are concerned about PERFORMANCE of **match... case** vs **if.. elif... else** they are **THE SAME**.

> As you can see, Python’s (andilabs: looking at assembly instructions) match-case statement is just a series of comparisons under the hood, exactly like the if-else method. This is why when we benchmarked the two approaches they performed equally.

source: https://betterprogramming.pub/pythons-match-case-is-too-slow-if-you-don-t-understand-it-8e8d0cf927d

### what about approach with dictionary?

side note about using old pythonic approach to switch with dictionary - it is slower, so with python 3.10+ and `match... case` it might become really old-fashion approach.